# How to make nested StackedLayouts in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qstackedwidget

I am creating a PyQt5 application in Python for a university project that uses `QStackedLayout` to make it a single-windowed app, however, I can not figure out how to nest a Stacked Widget inside a Stacked Widget.

When running the code (degraded for the question), you can see the main menu with a `QPushButton` in it. When clicking it, the window changes with a `QListWidget` in it.

What I want to achieve is a Stacked Widget to the right of the `QListWidget`, which changes respectively with the chosen list item.

Edit: is there a method to open one window where the other was positioned? Right now whenever I click a button the window pops up in the middle of the screen.

In the code, you can see the parts I am trying to implement with comment characters behind them.

The code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, 
                             QLabel, QPushButton, QWidget,
                             QStackedLayout, QListWidget)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, Qt

class Ui(QWidget):

    def setupUi(self, Main):

        Main.setObjectName("Main")
        Main.setFixedSize(900, 500)

        self.width = 900
        self.height = 500

        self.setFixedSize(self.width, self.height)

        '''MENU ON THE MAIN WINDOW'''
        self.menu = QStackedLayout()

        self. mainMenu = QWidget()
        self.howToMenu = QWidget()

        self. mainMenuUi()
        self.howToMenuUi()

        self.menu.addWidget(self. mainMenu)
        self.menu.addWidget(self.howToMenu)

        '''MENU ON THE HOWTO WINDOW'''        
        #self.howToMenuMenu = QStackedLayout()

        #self.howToOverView    = QWidget()
        #self.howToLevel       = QWidget()
        #self.howToTapeMeasure = QWidget()
        #self.howToTheodolite  = QWidget()

        #self.   overViewUi()
        #self.      levelUi()
        #self.tapeMeasureUi()
        #self. theodoliteUi()

        #self.howToMenuMenu.addWidget(self.howToOverView   )
        #self.howToMenuMenu.addWidget(self.howToLevel      )
        #self.howToMenuMenu.addWidget(self.howToTapeMeasure)
        #self.howToMenuMenu.addWidget(self.howToTheodolite )

    def mainMenuUi(self):

        self.mainMenu.setFixedSize(self.width, self.height)

        self.mainMenuText = QLabel(self.mainMenu)
        self.mainMenuText.setGeometry(QRect(30, 120, 480, 200))
        self.mainMenuText.setStyleSheet("font: 14pt Century Gothic")
        self.mainMenuText.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading|Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignTop)
        self.mainMenuText.setText("Welcome to the Surveying Traverse Calculator!")

        self.howToButton = QPushButton("HOW TO DO A TRAVERSE", self.mainMenu)

        self.howToButton.setGeometry(140, 180, 200, 30)

    def howToMenuUi(self):

        self.howToMenu.setFixedSize(self.width, self.height)

        self.menuButton1 = QPushButton("Back to main menu", self.howToMenu)   
        self.menuButton1.setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 200, 30))

        self.howToTitle = QLabel(self.howToMenu)
        self.howToTitle.setGeometry(QRect(10, 50, self.width, 40))
        self.howToTitle.setStyleSheet("font: 14pt Century Gothic")
        self.howToTitle.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading|Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.howToTitle.setText("How to Do a Traverse")

        self.howToSteps = QListWidget(self.howToMenu)
        self.howToSteps.setGeometry(QRect(10, 100, 200, 80))
        self.howToSteps.insertItem(0, "OVERVIEW"    )
        self.howToSteps.insertItem(1, "LEVEL"       )
        self.howToSteps.insertItem(2, "TAPE MEASURE")
        self.howToSteps.insertItem(3, "THEODOLITE"  )

    #def overViewUi(self):

    #def levelUi(self):

    #def tapeMeasureUi(self):

    #def theodoliteUi(self)

class Main(QMainWindow, Ui):

    def __init__(self):

        super(Main, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.menuButton1.clicked.connect(self. menuWindow)
        self.howToButton.clicked.connect(self.howToWindow)

    def menuWindow(self):

        self.menu.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def howToWindow(self):

        self.menu.setCurrentIndex(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    M = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]
You can add a `QStackedWidget` to the right of the `QListWidget` and control the chosen list object with the `currentRowChanged` signal. I would recommend you use `QHBoxLayout`, `QVBoxLayout`, or `QGridLayout` for layout management.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, 
                             QLabel, QPushButton, QWidget,
                             QStackedLayout, QListWidget,
                             QVBoxLayout, QStackedWidget,
                             QGridLayout)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, Qt

class Ui(QWidget):

    def setupUi(self, Main):

        Main.setObjectName("Main")
        Main.setFixedSize(900, 500)

        self.width = 900
        self.height = 500

        self.setFixedSize(self.width, self.height)

        '''MENU ON THE MAIN WINDOW'''
        self.menu = QStackedLayout()

        self.mainMenu = QWidget()
        self.howToMenu = QWidget()

        self.mainMenuUi()
        self.howToMenuUi()

        self.menu.addWidget(self.mainMenu)
        self.menu.addWidget(self.howToMenu)

        '''MENU ON THE HOWTO WINDOW'''        
        #self.howToMenuMenu = QStackedLayout()

        #self.howToOverView    = QWidget()
        #self.howToLevel       = QWidget()
        #self.howToTapeMeasure = QWidget()
        #self.howToTheodolite  = QWidget()

        #self.   overViewUi()
        #self.      levelUi()
        #self.tapeMeasureUi()
        #self. theodoliteUi()

        #self.howToMenuMenu.addWidget(self.howToOverView   )
        #self.howToMenuMenu.addWidget(self.howToLevel      )
        #self.howToMenuMenu.addWidget(self.howToTapeMeasure)
        #self.howToMenuMenu.addWidget(self.howToTheodolite )

    def mainMenuUi(self):

        self.mainMenu.setFixedSize(self.width, self.height)

        self.mainMenuText = QLabel(self.mainMenu)
        self.mainMenuText.setGeometry(QRect(30, 120, 480, 200))
        self.mainMenuText.setStyleSheet("font: 14pt Century Gothic")
        self.mainMenuText.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading|Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignTop)
        self.mainMenuText.setText("Welcome to the Surveying Traverse Calculator!")

        self.howToButton = QPushButton("HOW TO DO A TRAVERSE", self.mainMenu)

        self.howToButton.setGeometry(140, 180, 200, 30)

    def howToMenuUi(self):

        self.howToMenu_layout = QGridLayout()

        self.howToMenu.setFixedSize(self.width, self.height)

        self.menuButton1 = QPushButton("Back to main menu")
        self.menuButton1.setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 200, 30))

        self.howToTitle = QLabel()
        self.howToTitle.setGeometry(QRect(10, 50, self.width, 40))
        self.howToTitle.setStyleSheet("font: 14pt Century Gothic")
        self.howToTitle.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading|Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.howToTitle.setText("How to Do a Traverse")

        self.howToSteps = QListWidget()
        self.howToSteps.setGeometry(QRect(10, 100, 200, 80))
        self.howToSteps.insertItem(0, "OVERVIEW"    )
        self.howToSteps.insertItem(1, "LEVEL"       )
        self.howToSteps.insertItem(2, "TAPE MEASURE")
        self.howToSteps.insertItem(3, "THEODOLITE"  )
        self.howToSteps.currentRowChanged.connect(self.display_traverse)

        self.overview_container = QWidget()
        self.level_container = QWidget()
        self.tape_measure_container = QWidget()
        self.theodolite_container = QWidget()

        self.overViewUi()
        self.levelUi()
        self.tapeMeasureUi()
        self.theodoliteUi()

        self.traverse_action = QStackedWidget()
        self.traverse_action.addWidget(self.overview_container) 
        self.traverse_action.addWidget(self.level_container) 
        self.traverse_action.addWidget(self.tape_measure_container) 
        self.traverse_action.addWidget(self.theodolite_container) 
        self.traverse_action.setCurrentIndex(0)

        self.howToMenu_left_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.howToMenu_left_layout.addWidget(self.menuButton1)
        self.howToMenu_left_layout.addWidget(self.howToTitle)
        self.howToMenu_left_layout.addWidget(self.howToSteps)

        self.howToMenu_layout.addLayout(self.howToMenu_left_layout,0,0,1,1)
        self.howToMenu_layout.addWidget(self.traverse_action,0,1,1,1)
        self.howToMenu.setLayout(self.howToMenu_layout)

    def overViewUi(self):
        self.overview_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.overview_button = QPushButton('Overview')
        self.overview_layout.addWidget(self.overview_button)
        self.overview_container.setLayout(self.overview_layout)

    def levelUi(self):
        self.level_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.level_button = QPushButton('Level')
        self.level_layout.addWidget(self.level_button)
        self.level_container.setLayout(self.level_layout)

    def tapeMeasureUi(self):
        self.tape_measure_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.tape_measure_button = QPushButton('Tape measure')
        self.tape_measure_layout.addWidget(self.tape_measure_button)
        self.tape_measure_container.setLayout(self.tape_measure_layout)

    def theodoliteUi(self):
        self.theodolite_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.theodolite_button = QPushButton('Theodolite')
        self.theodolite_layout.addWidget(self.theodolite_button)
        self.theodolite_container.setLayout(self.theodolite_layout)

    def display_traverse(self, index):
        self.traverse_action.setCurrentIndex(index)

class Main(QMainWindow, Ui):

    def __init__(self):

        super(Main, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.menuButton1.clicked.connect(self.menuWindow)
        self.howToButton.clicked.connect(self.howToWindow)

    def menuWindow(self):

        self.menu.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def howToWindow(self):

        self.menu.setCurrentIndex(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    M = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following example a QHBoxLayout is placed in the centralwidget, and as a first element the QListWidget and as a second element the QStackedLayout. To make the change I use the currentRowChanged signal from QListWidget

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(central_widget)

        self.overview_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.fill_overview()
        self.level_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.fill_level()
        self.tape_measure_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.fill_tape_measure()
        self.theodolite_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.fill_theodolite()

        self.list_widget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()

        self.slay = QtWidgets.QStackedLayout()
        hlay.addWidget(self.list_widget)
        hlay.addLayout(self.slay)
        hlay.setStretch(0, 0)
        hlay.setStretch(1, 1)

        self.list_widget.currentRowChanged.connect(self.slay.setCurrentIndex)

        for w, text in (
            (self.overview_widget, "OVERVIEW"),
            (self.level_widget, "LEVEL"),
            (self.tape_measure_widget, "TAPE MEASURE"),
            (self.theodolite_widget, "THEODOLITE"),
        ):
            self.slay.addWidget(w)
            self.list_widget.addItem(text)

    def fill_overview(self):
        hlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.overview_widget)
        hlay.addWidget(
            QtWidgets.QLabel("Overview", alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        )
        self.overview_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:green;")

    def fill_level(self):
        hlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.level_widget)
        hlay.addWidget(
            QtWidgets.QLabel("Level", alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        )
        self.level_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:blue;")

    def fill_tape_measure(self):
        hlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tape_measure_widget)
        hlay.addWidget(
            QtWidgets.QLabel("Tape Measure", alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        )
        self.tape_measure_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;")

    def fill_theodolite(self):
        hlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.theodolite_widget)
        hlay.addWidget(
            QtWidgets.QLabel("Theodolite", alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        )
        self.theodolite_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:gray;")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 240)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```